# npm install completes but no executable produced

Tags: npm-install

When I try to install cordova using "npm install -g cordova", the install process completes noting that 486 packages were added, and no errors reported, but no executable was produced. I tried the same thing on another computer and cordova.exe was produced in user/AppData/Roaming/npm.

I tried installing other programs and likewise, no executable was produced.

I also ran the install in verbose mode, but saw noting unusual.

I am installing from an admin-level cmd prompt on Windows 10.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

A "normal" (non-global) install would be
`npm install cordova`

You'll find the executable in `node_modules/.bin` then.

Comment: no executable in any of the following:  
node.js/node_modules  
node.js/node_modules/npm  
node.js/node_modules/npm/node_modules  
   
node.js/node_modules/.bin does not exist  
node.js/node_modules/npm/node_modules/.bin does not exist  

My other windows 10 system has the executables in user/AppData/Roaming/npm

Comment: Are you looking a it in a Windows Explorer? Then you might have to enable "hidden" files.

Comment: I have hidden files enabled. I ran a search for Cordova.exe on the entire c drive with no results. I've since tried it on a third window 10 pc and it works perfectly. There's something unique about this system. I thought it might be interacting with another program, so I de-installed about 20 programs with no success. I have a new drive arriving tomorrow and will start with a fresh windows install. It's strange that npm does not post any errors.

Comment: not cordova.exe, just corodova. It is a runnable JavaScript (executable).

Comment: I'm sorry, I was actually searching for Cordova.cmd, which is what I find on a working system. On a working system I can execute Cordova from the command line, but on the failing system I get command not found.

Comment: @ArtDolimpio would you mind accepting the answer?